# CSS: Absolute positioning and overflow: hidden

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make a thumnail viewer whereby when you roll your mouse over the thumbnail, you get a thumbnail sized view of a larger email.  As you move around the thumbnail youll see various parts of the larger pictures.

You can see this [here](http://www.eatonlabs.net/) by rolling over the last (green) image.

When you roll over I swap images between the low res thumbnail and a higher res version.  For some reason this larger image is no longer bound by the `overflow: hidden` property of the parent. What do I have to do to get this to work?

**Update**

The `position: relative` property is currently set on the parent above the `.artwork` container that currently provides the `overflow: hidden`.  Adding `overflow: hidden` to the top level container works correctly but seems to negate the rounded border effect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use position:relative on your parent block.

This is because our child div is absolute positioned. But when you use absolute position, it refers to the first positionned parent. The first positionned parent is the first one to have a position: relative (or absolute) property

for the border radius problem, this is a firefox and chrome bug you can fix by using hacks. See it here :

[CSS3 border-radius clipping issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248734/css3-border-radius-clipping-issues)

EDIT : To summarize :

add position: relative to the div artwork. then add your border radius to the "a" parent tag

Comment: See my update.. Doing that prevents the rounded corners from rendering

Comment: look at my post again and look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248734/css3-border-radius-clipping-issues

Comment: Try adding `position: relative` to the immediate parent of the image.. The image then escapes the parent's box ignoring the overflow property

Comment: I've updated my post, I have success when adding the border-radius on the "a" tag and position relative to the artwork div

Comment: I can't get this working Jerome - would you mind posting the code? Thanks

Comment: I've refreshed your page and can't reproduce a working case... Have you changed something ?

Comment: Hi Jerome, I was tweaking stuff but have reverted it back to the way it was. Thanks

Comment: sorry, I can't reproduce it, maybe i've dream or this was the first image which was displayed and not the large one. You can find an alternate solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314207/webkit-not-respecting-overflowhidden-with-border-radius