# Webkit border-radius and overflow bug when using any animation/transition

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit, overflow

I am having getting a weird bug when I use a combination of `overflow`, `border-radius`, and `transition`. I have a div with an img inside of it:

```html
<a href="#" class="block size1 annualreport nonprofit">
    <div class="inner_block">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8uuZB.jpg" />
    </div>
</a>
```

The div has a `border-radius`, and overflow is set to hidden:

```css
body {background-color:#78735e;}

.block {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    overflow:hidden;
}
.size1 {
    width: 226px;
    height: 464px;
    min-width: 160px;
    max-width: 226px;
}
.inner_block {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.block img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.1s;
}

.block img:hover { width:115%; height:115%; }
```

When I hover over the img I have a transition that takes place which makes the image larger to create a zooming effect. The problem is that the `overflow` seems to break on the bottom left and bottom right of the image.

I have created a JSFiddle for you to see what I'm talking about. http://jsfiddle.net/dmcgrew/HuMrC/1/

It works fine in Firefox, but breaks in Chrome and Safari.

Anyone know what might be causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me because I can't have the clear border increasing the clickable area of the masked element, nor do I want it to obscure that of other elements (and setting the height to 100% didn't solve the issue). See [my answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16109635/1502691) for a possible solution.

Comment: Thanx for your question, was about to post my own :) Thanx!

Comment: Please look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001515/chrome-bug-border-radius-not-clipping-contents-when-combined-with-css-transiti
This is the final answer and best solution!

Comment: Related Chromium bug: [#157218](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157218).

Comment: Related Safari/Webkit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=68196

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I'm understanding the problem correctly as the image isn't loading. If you add `height: 100%;` to `.inner_block` does it help your issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/HuMrC/2/

Comment: Yep that seems to fix it. I was also just able to fix it by adding a border with transparent color to the .block div.

Answer (score 109):

I had the same exact issue. Adding this to the parent container solved it for me.

```
.transitionfix {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Still breaks in Safari, if you test my jsFiddle in Safari http://jsfiddle.net/d4h2t0Lt/

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me on both Chrome and Safari for Mac (v7.1.2). If you remove the /* FIX */ lines from the CSS file and then filter list by typing "ja", you'll see (on webkit) that Jay-z's avatar will ignore overflow & border-radius during animation. See my plunker here http://plnkr.co/ayRgf52URQQ5XLqQtZVJ

Comment: In a fresh Chrome, you could add `will-change: transform` property instead of the mixin. It’ll work the same.

Answer (score 6):

## -- Simple Solution --

On the same element that has the animation transition, simply add:

```css
.animated-item {
    will-change: transform; /* New line to add to your existing CSS */
}
```

> The `will-change` CSS property hints to browsers how an element is expected to change. Browsers may set up optimizations before an element is actually changed. These kinds of optimizations can increase the responsiveness of a page by doing potentially expensive work before they are actually required.
> ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change

Comment: This was correct solution for me

Comment: In my case I needed to not only apply `will-change: transform` to the element being animated (the parent) but also to the child `svg` element that I was animating.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced this issue on Safari(It's a known bug in safari); fixed it by applying `-webkit-mask-image` and it works for me perfectly. cheers

```
.block {
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I added minus z-index value for image and higher value for parent

```
li {z-index:10; overflow: hidden;}

li img {z-index: -10;}
```

Comment: z-index does not cancel out like this. This logic is flawed. Adding a z-index may help, but the reasoning (and having 2 like this) is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

[There's already an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58283449) about a CSS property for creating a new stacking context:

```
isolation: isolate;
```

Answer (score -1):

I've had an issue in the past like this while trying to zoom into a photo inside a div. I fixed it by adding rotation `scale(1.05) rotate(0.02deg)` to the scale transform 
(It actually removed the glitchy lines)

My issue today is getting the glitch lines off a translateY div hover effect. Surprisingly enough, I got rid of them by removing `overflow: hidden;`

Hopefully this helps future debuggers.

Answer (score -1):

It is a problem about stacking context.

We can use methods listed in [MDN - stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) to form a stacking context:

- `position: relative; z-index: 1;`
- `-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);`
- `opacity: 0.999;`
- `will-change: transform;`

For me personally, the first method is the best.