# Webkit ignoring overflow:hidden when background is animated with @keyframes

Tags: css, keyframe

I'm trying to zoom a background images masked by a circle using border radius. After some research I've learned there appears to be a webkit bug regarding border-radius masking absolutely positioned elements.

But in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/5m1n5xeg/1/

```
.circle{
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:407px;
    height:407px;
}

.circle .image{
    width:407px;
    height:407px;
    background:url(http://vurtmedia.co.uk/prev/wp-content/themes/EightDegree/images/_overlay/logo-bg3.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center; 
     -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 5s ease-out infinite;
        -moz-animation: animatedBackground 5s ease-out infinite;
        animation: animatedBackground 5s ease-out infinite;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
0% {
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
-moz-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: scale(4);
-moz-transform: scale(3.5);
transform: scale(3.5);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
-moz-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
0% {
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
-moz-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: scale(4);
-moz-transform: scale(3.5);
transform: scale(1.5);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
-moz-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
}
}
```

(which works perfectly in firefox) if you take off the keyframe animations in the css, you will see that the outer div masks the inner element as it should, in webkit also. It's when the animation is applied the overflow no longer works.

Here is another example of the affect I'm trying to achieve working perfectly on everything (including webkit) but only on hover, using transitions instead: http://jsfiddle.net/dhepce3p/

```
.circle .image{
    width:407px;
    height:407px;
    background:url(http://vurtmedia.co.uk/prev/wp-content/themes/EightDegree/images/_overlay/logo-bg3.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
   background-size: 100% 100%;
    transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
-moz-transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
-ms-transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
-o-transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
-webkit-transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
}

.circle .image:hover{
    background-size: 150% 150%;

}
```

Is there a way I could combine forces of these techniques somehow, or even another workaround altogether?

I've also read about using :after on the element as well as positioning a white square with a punched out circle over the top as a hack, but this needs to go over another texture and so needs to be transparent!

Comment: Please take a look at this answer that fixes with z-index: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001515/chrome-bug-border-radius-not-clipping-contents-when-combined-with-css-transiti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you face  a known bug, you may rethink the technic used and go for one that will do. Most of the time there is a few ways to achieve a similar visual effect.

Here i would say, drop the `transform:thingy bob ;`  and use `background-size` instead. Beside absolute positionning might not even be relevant to be used in that case.

make it simple as much as possible.
http://jsfiddle.net/5m1n5xeg/4/

```css
.circle {
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:407px;
    height:407px;
}
.circle .image {
    border-radius:inherit;
    width:407px;
    height:407px;
    background:url(http://vurtmedia.co.uk/prev/wp-content/themes/EightDegree/images/_overlay/logo-bg3.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 5s ease-out infinite;
    -moz-animation: animatedBackground 5s ease-out infinite;
    animation: animatedBackground 5s ease-out infinite;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    50% {
        background-size: 350% 350%;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
    50% {
        background-size: 350% 350%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

actually, i'm mot certain that you need all of [those prefix](http://jsfiddle.net/5m1n5xeg/7/) :)

Comment: Amazing, that's it! I didn't realise I could use background-size within the keyframes, didn't even think of that. Cheers :)