# webkit parent:hover image goes out of border-radius

Tags: browser, webkit, overflow, css

Currently working on this [website](http://benbyford.com/dev/new/) and for some reason on safari and chrome the transition on :hover of the round images overflows even when set to `overflow: hidden`.

[image]

Any help would be greatful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16681137/458679).

Add this properties to your `.mix-img` class:

```
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: -moz- isn't needed and it renders ok anyway. chrome seems to be working fine now but i think Safari hates the world. wish webkit was as good as moz at rendering

Comment: still having issues with rending in safari, seems to hate any sort of transition I through at it :(