# Having problems with CSS transform:scale or CSS transition in Chrome, Safari, Opera but fine in Firefox

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm working on a design and using CSS transform:scale, and transition. It works great in Firefox but in Chrome, Safari, and Opera its not working right. It is a circle zoom effect and in those browsers it goes into a square. Not sure what is going on and why it works in Firefox, but not other browsers.

Here is my CSS code:

```
    .picCircle { 
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
border-radius: 50%;
}

/*GROW*/
.grow img {
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all .85s ease;
     -moz-transition: all .85s ease;
       -o-transition: all .85s ease;
      -ms-transition: all .85s ease;
          transition: all .85s ease;
}

.grow img:hover {
display: inline-block;
 transform:scale(1.1);
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
-moz-transform:scale(1.1);
-ms-transform:scale(1.1);
-0-transform:scale(1.1);
}
```

And here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="grow picCircle"><a href="/guest-rooms.htm"><img class="img-responsive" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;" src="http://bnbwebsites.s3.amazonaws.com/5076/shutterstock_61226425_600x600.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="600" /></a></div>
  <h2>Guest Rooms</h2>
  <p>Graceful Bed &amp; Breakfast Inn features six well-appointed bedrooms that are furnished with comfortable antiques.</p>
  <a class="btn btn-white" style="letter-spacing: 1.2px; margin-top: 25px;" href="/guest-rooms.htm">Learn More</a></div>
```

Link to website:
http://newgracefulfullblue.mybnbwebsite.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a duplicate of the question here: [Webkit border-radius and overflow bug when using any animation/transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383632/webkit-border-radius-and-overflow-bug-when-using-any-animation-transition)

Created a fiddle using the second answer to that question (added the CSS recommendation in that answer to the .picCircle rule): http://jsfiddle.net/nnvhacLe/1/

NOTE: in the fiddle, I also removed `display: inline-block` from the img.grow:hover rule.