# Table with rounded borders and borders between rows

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a full width table that has rounded corners, a border around the entire table, and a border under each table row (except the last one, don't want to double up...).

My sample: http://jsfiddle.net/7xD64/13/

My code:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

table {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%
}
tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

This works perfectly in Chrome, but is broken in Safari (there is no outer border). If I remove the `overflow: hidden` it renders the outer border, but the table doesn't have rounded edges.

I've found a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10314897/863846) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736503/how-to-make-css3-rounded-corners-hide-overflow-in-chrome-opera/10296258#10296258), but they don't seem to work on tables (or, as is likely, I'm not implementing them properly).

Question: Is it possible to make a table that has the following and works in Chrome, Safari and IE(8+)?

1. border around the entire table
2. rounded edges (with border) for the table
3. borders at the bottom of each table row
4. table is full width

If is is possible, could you please update my fiddle / code to explain how it works? (I'm still getting started with CSS, and I get pretty confused about where to put the rules.)

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry that the question deserved a down vote, I'm happy to fix it. Could you please let me know what I should change to make it less down-vote-worthy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one div outside of your table and apply the border radius. Also use `last-child` property to remove the border for the last items.

CSS:

```
#mytable{
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid black;
}
.mytable {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}
.mytable tr td {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.mytable tr:last-child td {
border-bottom: 0px solid black;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="mytable">
<table class="mytable" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>One</td>
  <td>Two</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Three</td>
  <td>Four</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7xD64/12/)

Comment: Thanks for the response - I didn't down vote, promise!
I actually need the table `width: 100%` (sorry I didn't include it, I didn't think it'd matter). Is it possible to get the rows to also be full width in this case?

Comment: use `display:block` instead of `display:inline-block`

Comment: Hmmm, rows are still not full width: http://jsfiddle.net/7xD64/6/ I also tried setting the tr to `width: 100%` and the td to `width: 50%` without success http://jsfiddle.net/7xD64/8/

Comment: Downvoter is right. The way I try to find a answer is wrong. I am going to update my answer soon. wait for a min.

Comment: Yay! It works, thank you very much! I have accepted and up voted. No idea why it was down voted :(

Answer (score 1):

Your Updated jsFiddle Table [**Your Table**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_eirenaios/7xD64/14/)

General table [**Bordered Table**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_eirenaios/L46FX/1317/)

> HTML

```
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> CSS

```
 table {
max-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: transparent;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border-spacing: 0;
border:1px solid #ddd;
border-radius:15px;
overflow:hidden;

}
thead {
    display: table-header-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
}
tr {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
}
.table thead>tr>th, .table tbody>tr>th, .table tfoot>tr>th, .table thead>tr>td, .table tbody>tr>td, .table tfoot>tr>td {
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
}
tr {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this works (although there's a weird double border at the very top). I accepted @suresh-ponnukalai's answer since it was more simple and was easy to implement. But I still up voted for a correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code for rounded border and it should work in all browsers

```
table {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I didn't down vote, promise!
The solution you gave doesn't seem to work in safari http://jsfiddle.net/7xD64/5/ Did I miss something?

Comment: I put your code in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7xD64/5/ and if you look at it in Safari you can see that the table border doesn't render.